# slackbots API and Slack’s new granular permissions incompatible?

Tags: npm, slack, slack-api

I’ve been getting my feet wet with developing simple Slack apps using the `slackbots` api. However, it seems that with Slack’s new granular app permissions, `slackbots` does not like the tokens. Anytime I plug in the tokens and start my app, I get a `not_allowed_token_type`error. My older apps and their tokens work fine, so I figure it has to do with the new permissions. Has anybody come across this and know a workaround?

Comment: It looks like this is the best workaround until the API can be updated to handle the new scoping https://api.slack.com/apps?new_classic_app=1